# Is Theano using back-propagation?

Tags: neural-networks, deep-learning, gradient-descent

I am following the following tutorial:

http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/mlp.html

Which is about training an Multilayer Perceptron (MLP) for the MNIST data set.

As far as I understand what **Theano** does is to use symbolic differentiation to calculate the gradient. With this calculated it is easy to implement **Gradient Descent** and I believe Theano does it with the following lines:
`gparams = [T.grad(cost, param) for param in classifier.params]`

Now my question: 
Given that *Back Propagation is a form of Gradient Descent* is Theano in fact using backpropagation? in other words, is it different to use gradient descent symbolically and actually implementing the backward pass in some cases? is it more stable or more prone to errors?

I guess that in most of the cases the results should be the same but I am wondering about it.

Thanks in advance and all the best,

Comment: Back Propagation is a form of Gradient Descent ?? back-prop is evaluating errors at each layers with respect to objective function to derive gradients of weights and biases efficiently. Gradient descent is update rule for these gradients.

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Gradient descent tells you that you should move in the direction of the gradient. Back propagation tells you how to calculate those gradients. How would you  phrase it more properly?

My point is that both move in the direction of the gradient, but Theano will do it symbolically and BP explicitly. So the question is: when does that lead to different results?

Comment: I didn't understand some point you made. As far as I now, Theano derives both error derivatives and gradients of weights and biases symbolically (algebraically) as it knows what is each component and how they are connected. What do you mean my 'doing it explicitly'?. It doesn't change anything at all rather than evaluation gradients analytically (symbolic) as we do it by hand. If you ask about if the derivation is numeric rather than analitic no it is not.

Comment: By explicitly in Back Propagation I mean that you will have to put the expressions (as in hard-coded) yourself and then do a loop that calculates them at every step on the loop. I was referring to what an usual implementation of BP will look like in opposition to what Theano is doing (symbolically deriving the gradients). 

I guess my question could be rephrased in the following way:

If a normal BP implementation is correct will it give the sample results than Theano if all the other variables are held constant?

Thanks for taking the time to make me clarify myself, by the way.

Comment: Yes, it will give the same result since 'explicit' derivation is the same with Theano's symbolic derivation.

Answer (score 6):

Theano creates a symbolic graph. This graph allows it to compute derivatives based on the connected inputs, the [Op](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/graphstructures.html#op) implemented on the Variables, and the output(created by the [Apply](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/extending/graphstructures.html#apply) Node).

```
import theano.tensor as T
x = T.dmatrix('x')
y = T.dmatrix('y')
z = x + y
```

[image: Theano Symbolic Graph]

The Apply nodes are blue, Variables are red, Op is green, and Types are purple.

As given in the theano official documentation,

> Having the graph structure, computing automatic differentiation is simple. The only thing tensor.grad() has to do is to traverse the graph from the outputs back towards the inputs through all apply nodes (apply nodes are those that define which computations the graph does). For each such apply node, its op defines how to compute the gradient of the node’s outputs with respect to its inputs. Note that if an op does not provide this information, it is assumed that the gradient is not defined. Using the chain rule these gradients can be composed in order to obtain the expression of the gradient of the graph’s output with respect to the graph’s inputs .
>
> Comparing with the Python language, an Apply node is Theano’s version of a function call whereas an Op is Theano’s version of a function definition.

While finding derivatives by hand is simple for feed forward neural networks, it becomes exceedingly complex in the case of Recurrent Neural Networks and Long Short Term Memory Cells, especially if the network is deep.

Answer (score 1):

I think that when you refer to "backpropagation" here you're really meaning "automatic differentiation".  The alternative would be "symbolic differentiation", where you find a formula for the derivative of some loss wrt some parameter and compute gradients according to that formula.

Theano sort of combines both.  Each Op defines a function for the forward pass and a function for propagating the gradient back, and theano takes care of passing signals between these functions to implement backpropagation.  This alone would just be (reverse mode) automatic differentiation.

The thing is theano also has an optimizer which can simplify expressions to reduce computation (eg $x_1\cdot W+x_2\cdot W \rightarrow (x_1+x_2)\cdot W$) or for numerical stability, which makes it a bit more like symbolic differentiation.

There's more discussion on the topic [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/theano-users/mln5g2IuBSU).